# Adobe CQ5: List only installed packages

Tags: curl, aem, crx

Right now I am using below command to fetch all package names in my CQ5 instance.

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp?cmd=ls
```

But this is giving me all packages like Installed , uninstalled but not deleted and uploaded package details.

But I am trying to fetch only installed packages.

Is there any way around ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse and use http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/list.jsp JSON response to get this details

Comment: can someone tell why its voted negative, both question and answer?

Comment: @IanMacDonald , the link on this answer is not the same as the question.
Was the question or answer edited after you comment?!
An I have the same questions about the down votes.